# I've been trying for an hour to remove the underline from links; I don't understand why something that should be so simple is so difficult

Tags: links, text

I don't want links to be underlined. It's that simple.

If you search google for this problem there's a ton of people asking how to do the same thing, going back more than a decade. So clearly this is an issue that many people have encountered; that must mean there's a simple solution right? A checkbox somewhere? An "underline links: true/false" option? Nope. No biggie, surely there's a plugin to do this? Nope.

Great, so now I have to mess with CSS/html, whatever. I've tried every variation of "text-decoration:none;" I could find. Pasted it everywhere there was to paste it. Pasted it in the style.css. Went through all of the theme's code making sure there wasn't anything doing this. Nothing. Did the same with borders, boxes, and outlines. Nothing. Even when I edit the block itself in html, it says right there "{text-decoration:none;}". Still there. Nothing should be making the underlines but they're still there. Tried different browsers, still there.

This is my first experience with making a webpage, and WordPress, and this has been one of the most frustrating experiences of my life. Unless I'm missing something obvious, I cannot understand how something so simple can be such a headache. I cannot understand how after *more than a decade* of people having the same problem, that there has been no attempt to address it. And I can't understand how there a dozen different solutions offered and *none* of them work.

So please, will someone finally tell me what I need to do to remove underlines from links before I punch a hole in my wall?

Comment: Can you share markup so we know what we're dealing with? ‍♂️

Comment: No-one can answer this definitely without seeing code, but regardless, this is not a WordPress specific question and should be asked elsewhere.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  This is a general CSS issue unfortunately, not specific to WordPress.

Comment: If this is the thought you have when addressing this...  `Great, so now I have to mess with CSS/html, whatever.` then this most likely isn't a place where you're going to get much help.  WPSE isn't a user-guide for WordPress themes and plugins, it's a developer Q/A forum specifically for diving into code.

Comment: There's a custom CSS box in the customizer you don't need to modify the themes `style.css` ( your changes will be lost when the theme updates ). Eitherway this is a generic CSS problem, not a WordPress problem. You should ask on stackoverflow instead

Answer (score 3):

Something like this *should* work; but without being able to see your markup, it's hard to know for sure.

```
a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And while I typically try to stay away from `!important`, sometimes it comes in handy. I'll let you be the judge for your project on whether or not to do it this way:

```
a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

[Specificity in CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) is something you may want to read more about, though. It would also be a good idea to get familiar with Chrome's Developer Tools (specifically Inspector), and how to use it to troubleshoot your CSS from the frontend.

Comment: Would sure like to know why my (correct) answer is being downvoted. It's not like I was the one that asked the question in the wrong forum; the OP did that. But my answer shouldn't be penalized. That's kinda BS. Kinda makes people not want to contribute 

Comment: Someone else voted it up, without them commenting none of us will know why they downvoted

Comment: Does seem harsh. FWIW I’ve given you an upvote for encouragement.

Comment: Hehe, thanks for the encouragement Andy!